# Making reference to other layers/output in process modeler

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-modeler, referencing

Update:
Adding example of line layer and point layers per @ConfusedButterfly request.

Below is a close up zoom of the line layer.
[image: Example of Line Layer]

Below is the zoom out of the point layers (65 points).
[image]

===================Post Update 21 Oct 22===========

I have simplified the model down to just the trouble step to make it easier to review (at suggestion of @ConfusedButterfly). It seems right now the trouble is that I cannot get the `Translate` function to read input from my point layers (more than 1 points). Unfortunately, still does not work.

[image: Screenshot#1 - Simplified model]

I tried 2 ways to reference in point layer input (`Translate` function seem to only take single number input as the Model Input). The expression i used and the error message log are per below. Screnshot# 2 below show one of the expression and screenshot#3 show the log's output

- Try#1:
  Expression: `to_real(x(geometry(get_feature_by_id(@wtglayout,'"Inst_Check"'))))` Log Message: No reported error. But the delta X on log was report as "None" and the Line Layer was not translated.
- Try#2:
  Expression:
  `dbvaluebyid(@wtglayout,'X','Inst_Check')`. Error Log: "Could not evaluate expression for parameter DELTA_X for Translate: Error: invalid targetLayerName"

[image: Screenshot#2]

[image: Screenshot#3]
======================Original Post==========================

I'm trying to build a process model to automate my future works. I have got most of it to work until the very last step.
In the last step, I need to translate a set of duplicated lines (an algorithm output from previous steps) to new location. The x & y off-set value for this algorithm output needs to be read from a point layer (a model input). You can see these highlighted steps/inputs/outputs on the screenshot below.

In the translate step window, I have tried to reference to the model input layer in several ways(called "Point Coordinates"/in the expression dialog, this is referenced as *@wtglayout*)  but have not been successful so far. I keep getting error messages. Example of the expression I used and the corresponding error codes are below (one example screenshot to help visualize below too).

- Code: `x(@wtglayout)` Error: `Could not evaluate expression for parameter DELTA_X for Translate: Cannot convert to geometry`
- Code: `x(geometry(@wtglayout))` Error: `Could not evaluate expression for parameter DELTA_X for Translate: Cannot convert to feature`
- Code: `x(geometry(get_feature_by_id(@wtglayout,'ID')))` Error: No error here. But the vector layer that was supposed to translate did not translate at all which suggests that the expression returned zero or NULL value.

I know I can do this translation step with no issue outside of Process Modeler but would really like to be able to automate this.

[image: Screenshot 1 Process Model]

[image: Screenshot 2 Translate Step Input]

[![Screehshot 3 Expression Dialogue][8]][8]

Comment: You have `Join attributes by field value` and `Point Coordinates` as input to `Translate`. Try to load those two layers and create a simpler model using those layers as input. If you can do the process outside of the modeler, try to debug by outputting the offset distance expression you put in offset distance using `native:raisewarning`. If all seems to be correct, maybe it's a dependence problem. It's a good practice to only explicitly set dependence in the modeler only to the algorithm that has no direct input-output connection to avoid facing race conditions.

Comment: Thanks @ConfusedButterfly, i have set up a simplified model using the direct inputs. But still no luck. I have updated original post with this simplified model and additional screenshot.

Comment: Please revise your question to focus it on where you are currently stuck.

Comment: @NghiaHa can you share an example layers for `Line layer` and the `Point layer`

Comment: @PolyGeo, i have updated the question with the specific steps where i have the issue above. This has been made clear from the original post.

Comment: @ConfusedButterfly, i've added the example layers per your request.

Comment: It looks like you’ve tacked two updates onto your original question rather than revising your original question. I think this makes it less readable and less attractive to potential answerers.